# Windows Security authentication dialog freezes

Tags: windows-10, security, freeze, windows-authentication

Since a few weeks ago, when my Windows 10 Pro computer has displayed a Windows Security authentication dialog like this:

[image: one]

It awaits input from me but then freezes instantly as soon as I click the OK button, the Cancel button, or the Close X icon at the upper right, regardless of whether I've filled in the password. Nothing happens further. The dialog never closes and I get no error message. I also can't find a related issue in any of the Windows logs.

This had been happening with a remote desktop connection to one server, but switching to the Remote Desktops manager fixed that, because now it uses a different interface to have me authenticate. I had also been happening when I'd open an Excel file from SharePoint, but I made some change last week that eliminated that problem. Now it's happening every time I open Outlook.

I've Googled phrases like **"Windows Security" dialog freeze** without success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perform a Clean Boot to avoid the software conflict. Repair Office.
Also, create a new account to check result.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up Clean Boot and ran one. The problem persisted! The same happened after I ran a diagnostic boot. But, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of using Procmon to isolate what exactly is happening, I'd recommend a few things.

-Create a new account to check if the behavior occurs there as well.
-Repair Office via add/remove programs (Select Modify)
-Run Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

If this is isolated to the Office Suite, try backing up your PST/OST files and uninstalling/reinstalling it.
If those don't resolve your issue, post results here.

I'd move this to the Windows 10 forum though, this isn't a Security issue as much as an application/OS issue.

Comment: The only StackExchange forum that turns up when I search for Windows is Windows Phone. Also, this isn't the security forum, it's the superuser forum.

Answer (score 0):

One resource led me to the Credential Manager, where I found a Windows credential for Office that I deleted. Now I'm no longer getting the prompt to log in, with Outlook evidently using my network credentials as it always used to do.